# Is there any way to call our view to different notebooks in SPARK SQL?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am new to data bricks and I am working basically on SQL there. I have created a temp view in one notebook and that particular view I have to re-use again in a  different notebook. Is there any elegant way to do it? To make the view Public or something. Please let me know.

Comment: are these notebooks executed on the same cluster or on different?

Comment: same cluster. Sorry, I should be clear.